# EF 6.1.2 Database First View Generation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 with Database-First and have tried to precompile views to reduce the startup time using this project: https://efinteractiveviews.codeplex.com/

```
using (var ctx = new DBContext())
            {
                InteractiveViews
                    .SetViewCacheFactory(
                        ctx,
                        new FileViewCacheFactory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\views.xml"));
            }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any effect on startup time or related queries. Is there another method how i can generate views through a t4 template or check if the views are set at all?

Regarding the t4 templates, the ones i have found online are only for code first setups.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to section 2.4.1 of  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/hh949853.aspx), seems in most cases EF6 doesn't need any view generation for speed optimization. So it is better to check does adding view really improve speed? Anyway as mention on previous link, you could try "Framework Power Tools or programmatically as described in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601)"